# Cached AMP page content not consistent with the AMP content on my site

Tags: amp-html

I have a dynamic website that shows a list of events around a particular area that gets updated up to several times per day. I have made AMP versions of some pages and made them discoverable to Google. An example is:

https://estatesales.org/amp/estate-sales/ak/anchorage

The same URL within the Google AMP cache is picking up totally different content, and seems to include ALL of the events we have in our database, rather than just events around Anchorage, AK:

https://estatesales-org.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/estatesales.org/amp/estate-sales/ak/anchorage

If the AMP version of the page on our site is showing the correct content all the time since the beginning of when we made them discoverable, I don't see how this would be possible. It seems to be throwing off the server side code logic in some way when it stores the cached version of the page. Anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

They look identical to me. As of this writing, there is no listing near AK and the page is showing listing from other states.